# Embed and unpack referenced assembly purely in memory

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli, mixed-mode

Say I have the given build structure:

- **MyApp.exe** - *.NET module*
- **MyLib.Dll** - *C++/CLI module*

How do I pack MyLib.dll into MyApp.exe as an embedded resource, and unpack MyLib.dll at startup without writing the Dll into the file system? (thus keeping it purely in memory)

1. I can embed the Dll using the Solution Explorer in VS
2. At runtime I unpack the Dll using `GetManifestResourceStream`
3. Then what? How do I "integrate" this unpacked Dll into the current context such that the rest of the program finds the assembly classes, without writing the Dll to disk?

**Edit :** Dependency merging tools such as ILMerge cannot be used, since the Dll is a mixed-mode assembly, and no typical tools are able to merge it.

**Edit :** I can unpack the Dll to a file (documented [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource)) and use `Assembly.LoadFile()`
But I still cannot do this purely in memory, writing the Dll to a file making it vulnerable to thieves who can find the Dll and use it in their own app.

Comment: Mixed-mode assemblies should be stored on disk, a requirement for executable files that contain native code.  If you want a single deliverable executable then name it setup.exe, created with, say, [this addin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks Hans! I think your word is final since you are an expert on the subject. I rest my case.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to embed and unpack mixed-mode assemblies.

- **[Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)** - automated embedding and unpacking of all used assemblies marked "Copy Local"
- **Manual method** - mark assembly "Embedded resource" and unpack using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource)

Comment: For C++/CLI - But all of the above methods actually store a copy of the assembly on disk before running it. This is a requirement for executables that contain native code.